# CRUD API и разделение сущностей

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel5

У меня есть таблицы со связью многие ко многим

```
People -> label_person <- Labels
```

Имеется контроллер `PersonController` с CRUD внутри для работы с таблицей `People`. В этом же контроллере есть ещё один метод - `sync_labels` для синхронизации меток с таблицей `label_person`.

```
public function sync_labels(Person $person, Request $request): LabelCollection
{
    $person->labels()->sync($request->input('label_ids', []));

    return new LabelCollection($person->labels);
}
```

С контроллером этим работаю по API. И есть пару вопросов у меня

1. Допустимо ли в контроллере `PersonController` размещать метод `sync_labels`, который имеет не прямое отношение к сущности `Person`?
2. Что метод `sync_labels` должен возвращать в качестве ответа? Только `labels`, как у меня в коде выше? Или же `Person` с его `labels`? Т.е. только как бы "затронутые данные"?
3. Нужно ли разделять методы? Сейчас у меня по факту два метода `update` - сам update для таблицы `People` и отдельный update для таблицы `label_person`. Нужно ли объединять их в один? Вопрос тесно связан со вторым вопросом - какой должен быть ответ?

Answer (score 1):

1. PersonController - должен только контролировать процесс,  синхронизацию лучше вынести в репозиторий (класс, где будет происходить все манипуляции с БД). Это паттерн репозиторий https://habr.com/ru/post/248505/
2. sync_labels может возвращать любые данные, которые вам нужны. Но судя по названию он должен только синхронизировать и ни чего больше (вернуть просто пустоту). Я бы назвал метод контроллера labels и вызвал там из репозитория sync_labels, а затем получил метки и get_labels тоже из репозитрия (в дальнейшем может появиться функционал, получения меток по дате, алфавиту и прочее). Это тоже лучше хранить в репозитории.

   ```
   public function labels(Person $person, Request $request): 
   LabelCollection

   {

       $this->repo_labels->sync_labels($request->input('label_ids');

       return $this->repo_labels($person);

   }
   ```
3. Вы можете в обновлении People вызывать метод синхронизации из репозитория $this->repo_labels->sync_labels если вам нужно. Думаю объеденять нет смысла, пусть у вас будет обновления People (там вы можете обновлять все что угодно) и обновление только label_person (обновление только меток)